# NotFound Controller on mvc website

Tags: model-view-controller, web, controller

On A c# mvc website, I created a controller with the name NotFound, and then created a default route to an index action on the controller. When I debugged the program it went to the correct controller action but did not display anything in the view. Does any one know why?

Answer (score 0):

did you do:

```
return View("some view name");
```

in the action method?

what does the `some view name.aspx` contain?

Comment: The view was called NoFound.spark, so I did not specify a view name. The view just contained some text

Comment: Ok so you at least did `return View();`. Have you configured the spark view engine correctly?  http://dev.dejardin.org/documentation/configuring